# XE2 exe and dcu location

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I am attempting to move to XE2 from Delphi 6.

When I compile and create an exe the exe and dcu appear to be put in the \win32\debug directory under the project.

Is there any way to have it put the exe and dcu in the same directory as the project and source?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? This kind of separation is here to make your project folders clean, to separate your source files from compiled units files. I don't see any valid reason to keep all files together. Even in older versions of Delphi where this kind of separation didn't exist, I always created a DCU folder to hold compiled units. Unless you have a specific reason for that, don't do it.

Comment: This prevents you from having both debug and release versions of your DCUs and executable, which is often preferable. It will also break things for you when and if you add Win64 as a target, because the 64-bit executable will overwrite the 32-bit (or vice versa), and you won't be able to have both exist at the same time without extra work. It will also mean that every time you switch from debug to release or 32 to 64 bit, a full build will be needed in order to make sure you don't have mixed-up DCUs in your executable.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Go to the project options and remove these:

[image]

Comment: +1 for proper answer, but this will have implications pointed out by Ken White.

Comment: I found that the smart thing to do is leave these options as they default, but then add a shortcut in the project folder to the exe. This makes for quick access, and maintains the separations.